# Promote Music.SE at NAMM & Musikmesse

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A good way to meet people from the music industry (blogs, press, professionals, music fans...) would maybe to be present in the next [MusikMesse](http://musik.messefrankfurt.com/frankfurt/en/besucher/willkommen.html) (March 21-24 in Frankfurt, Germany) or [NAMM](http://www.namm.org/) (January 19-22 in Anaheim, California) - it's maybe a little late for the latter to organize something.
It would be a nice occasion to let [Bubbles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/) meet some music enthousiasts !

I don't plan to be there but maybe some of the music.SE users will, what can we / the CHAOS team do to help them promote this site ?

Comment: Cool.  At minimum I'm sure they could provide stickers and such if we have someone who can go to an event like these.

Comment: NAMM doesn't seem to be open to public so maybe it would be harder to have someone promote us there. Germany is far from the US but it seems to be more open :)

Comment: Are there users already scheduled to attend? Are there users who are interested in going? If so, [see this meta post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/software-craftsmanship-north-america-2011-sponsorship-proposal) for an example of what possibilities exist as next steps. Also, are there other music/musicianship conferences later in the year? Do these occur at roughly the same time each year? What about US-based organizations like [NAfME](http://www.menc.org/)?

Comment: I hope there are some people here that will attend them !
I think these are the most notable (at least in Europe, MusikMesse is the biggest) and they occur every year around the same date.
There are not so many big fairs, but I also found : Summer NAMM (Nashville, USA - July - http://www.namm.org/summer/2012), Dallas Guitar Show (Dallas, USA - April - https://www.guitarshow.com/), Popkomm (Berlin, Germany - September), Musicora (Paris, France - May - http://www.musicora.com/salon.html), Music & You (Paris, France - September, but I think it's been cancelled)

Answer (score 3):

Occasionally I go to Winter NAMM, but I did not go this year. I usually go to Summer NAMM in July in Nashville, Tennessee. I don't go as a member of the public; I get a badge from any one of a number of music industry organizations or musical instrument businesses that I'm affiliated with professionally. In fact [at the last Summer NAMM I presented a lecture in a conference room](http://wheatwilliams.com/wordpress/2011/07/22/im-helping-teach-a-class-at-summer-namm-on-saturday/). It was on music apps for iPads.

If, by next July, you have concrete ideas about promoting Music.SE, please contact me and I'll use my connections to get the word out. For instance, if you can provide me with printed flyers, that would be really useful--remember, this is a meatspace event where people shake hands and fill up tote bags with flyers and brochures.

Oh, and if Stack Exchange wants to buy me an airplane ticket to Frankfurt, please know that I speak German.

Comment: I would give an extra +1 just for the last sentence... :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Summer NAMM is July 12-14, 2012, in Nashville, Tennessee](http://www.namm.org/summer/2012). I am planning on going.

If the CHAOS team have specific ideas about promoting Music.SE there, please contact me at wheat@wheatwilliams.com.

Comment: We actually just revamped/published an "official guide" to getting conference sponsorship. Take a look and email the team if you're interested. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference