# Attracting musicians to Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Throughout my time here I have noticed that a large majority of those on the Musical Practice & Performance SE are one or another type of computer programmer with some musical knowledge.

While this participation is good, and I'm not suggesting that they're not "real" musicians, I was wondering how SE might attract more musicians with formal training to the site to (hopefully) take it out of Beta and provide a more consistent and thorough knowledge base?

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that the "Beta state" of the site itself is holding us back. This is not a big deal for programmers, as it's a known concept to them. But for non-programmers, it's more likely to give a perception of "not serious" and "unfinished". In my view this gives the wrong impression as the StackExchange engine is in no way an unfinished product. It's a well-tuned engine that works perfect in every aspect of what it's intended for.

So my wish for a while has been to give the site a "released" look although still in beta. It is not unheard of, as the UX site did get it's finished theme while still in beta, but with the word "beta" still visible in the logo. I think a better look with a more "musical" GUI theme will attract more new "non-programmer" users.

The site has been around for a long time, and it is still growing, although not enough in all the aspects that would tip us over to full graduation. But enough to prove that the site is here to stay.

Answer (score 1):

My plan was this: [I'm going to print up some flyers to distribute at music colleges](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/im-going-to-print-up-some-flyers-to-distribute-at-music-colleges)

It is aiming at those undergoing tuition, rather than professionals, but I hope it will work. I'm going with that fleet detail as final unless you have improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been Promoting this place On Google Plus to various musical communities, whenever the topic of places to learn comes up: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/105787214854522083467

http://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory and
http://www.reddit.com/r/guitar were recommended in a few other places, might be worth spending some time on there and seeing How we compare.

Other than that I think our best source of musicians is out there in the real world.

What about getting in contact with some institutions of music around the country.  Personally, if we could get one of the guys from Guitar Techniques, or Pat Pattinson(the songwriting teacher at Berklee) I would be stoked! And getting just one or 2 tribe leaders as their called would skyrocket the user count on the site!

Comment: Although you are not too happy about using it mainly for promotion purposes...  https://plus.google.com/104685721640008510812/posts/9ERD2pQdMp6 . I agree with you, and that is why we should be careful to come out as good content in form of a link as a responsive help to a partiqular question, or a "favorite" question with value in itself with a good comment along the link.

Comment: sorry, do you mean we should be careful that we appear as good content when we link to a question on an external site, or do you mean in general when answering questions?

Comment: I just mean that when posting link to Music SE on other communities, it should be in the form of useful content on those sites, and not just advertising our site just for the sake of advertising.

Comment: Of Course!  People in G+ communities like guitar music theory are looking to improve their theory knowledge in a non-partisan way(so there's less bias based on the teacher's belief) and that's exactly what music.stackexchange is.  The only way I benefit from bringing people to the site is higher quality answers, because my rep is based on good answers, not on fans.

Answer (score 0):

If some people here go to [big music events like NAMM](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/promote-music-se-at-namm-musikmesse) this can be a good opportunity to promote this site, but it might need something more organized than just some people distributing flyers. That's why I suggested having [Bubbles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/) there (does SE still do that ?) or being present in a booth through a partnership with a company that is already there. Maybe something related to learning instrument, a school, an sheet editor, Arobas Music (Guitar Pro)...