# If we could promote our site at exhibitions or events, which ones would we choose?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

For some reason I came across [this old question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/148/104) on promoting Music.SE by wearing or giving out T-Shirts at the big Music Conferences and Exhibitions.
Then I saw [this one](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/314/104) asking what the Chaos team could do to help - unfortunately I think that team no longer exists.

Obviously back then we didn't have a design or logo, but now we do, I think it's worth revisiting.

Obviously we'll need to check to see if SE can support this by providing something like a conference pack, but if allowed, what events do we think would be worthwhile, and why?

Getting something with our logo **and** URL available to hand out (pens, stickers, cards etc) or to wear (t-shirts) would get us known by an astonishingly wide range of members of the music community.

Answer (score 5):

[NAMM](https://www.namm.org/thenammshow/2017) seems to be the biggest annual Music Show - hosted in Anaheim, California. NAMM2017 is Jan 19-22 2017.

It is self titled:

> the global family reunion of the music products, pro audio, live sound, lighting and entertainment technology communities...

showcasing

> the world’s leading brands across music products, pro audio, live sound, lighting and entertainment...

Answer (score 4):

[MusikMesse, in Frankfurt](https://musik.messefrankfurt.com/frankfurt/en/aussteller/willkommen.html), from the 5th to 8th of April 2017 is Europe's

> international trade fair for musical instruments, sheet music, music
>   production and marketing.

Comment: Never been to NAMM, but I have a lot of <strike> happy </strike> memories of Messe ;)